BigQuery user_pseudo_id strange format
I know that user_pseudo_id format in BigQuery is usually 123456.654321. However, I found user_pseudo_ids like this one: zzlrlIWWmuO2pGInTOt8ayOT3Gq7LXiyD7jU4ayH+4M=.1835253951.
I am testing server-side setup, so I have both server-side GTM and client-side GTM. They are sending data to separate data streams in same GA4 through same GTM container, so the data is theoretically the same.
However, when I check BigQuery data, I have 20,000 user_pseudo_ids in client-side stream that are not found in server stream (but are of normal/expected format). I also have additional 20,000 that are in server-side only, and most of them have this weird format. Some of the ids are found in both streams.
Does anyone know the cause of this? How to fix it? Shouldn't all (or at least 95%) data be the same in both streams?
To clarify, the goal is to make server collect data properly, and then I will shut down the first data stream.
I tried joining data to see if some weird IDs actually match the expected ones (they fired at the same time, etc.), but couldn't find anything.
